# Converting a time value from varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a varchar column [Start_time (hh:mm)] with data in this format:

```
11:18:00 a.m.
```

This is consistent throughout the column, aside from a few NULLS.

I have created a new column [StartTime] with datetime datatype to receive the converted values.

I have tried CAST:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET StartTime = CAST([Start_time (hh:mm)] AS DATETIME)
```

And I've also tried convert:

```
UPDATE dbo.mytable
SET StartTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, [Start_time (hh:mm)], 120)
```

I use 120 because it matches the datetime format we are using in the database, I guess the date part would just be the default. I have also tried 108, because it's only the time coming through, but that doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: what is the date? I only see a time? do you want to convert it to a time data type? Or do you want to concat today's date to the time and then convert it?

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to put only a time into a DateTime column.. among other syntax issues.  You could give it a generic date i suppose, but that seems like a bad choice.

Comment: Well, the date data is stored in a different column, and there's a good reason behind that.

But I need this time to go into a datetime column because it has to interact with an older version of Access, which can't deal with Time as a datatype.

Comment: A generic date is fine. We have the real date in another column, so we will just ignore the generic date from this new column at the end of the day.

Comment: Instead of `[Start_time (hh:mm)]`, pick an arbitrary date such as '2014-03-23' and prepend it to the time like so: `'2014-03-23' + ' ' + [Start_time (hh:mm)]`.

Comment: I've figured it out now, but I can't answer my own question for another 5 hours. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error was caused by the dots in 'a.m.'

So I got rid of those:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET [Start_time (hh:mm)] = REPLACE([Start_time (hh:mm)], '.', '')
```

Then this worked fine:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET StartTime = CAST([Start_time (hh:mm)] AS DATETIME)
```

Output example:

```
1900-01-01 11:18:00.000
```

We will ignore the "default" date when it matters, as we have the real date values stored in another column.

Thanks for the advice guys.